# Magento version Updating 2.4.2 to 2.3.0

Tags: magento2.3.0, downgrade

Dear all getting isssue when i run below commnd.

**composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps :

1. Back up the `composer.json` file.

> cp composer.json composer.json.bak

2. Remove the current version.

> composer remove magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 --no-update

3. Then install the required version.

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update

Comment: Dear Same error on second command.
composer remove magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 --no-update

Comment: Any Other Idea ?